# Does mutating arguments always introduce order dependent behaviour?

Tags: java, functional-programming, mutation

I've been informed that mutation causes methods to be order dependent (e.g. [Mutation](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs2102/common/kathi-notes/mutation-part2.html))

However, given the following methods (ignore null for simplicity) I can't see how either would ever behave differently given the same argument.

```
void x(StringBuffer s) {
    s.append("a");
}

StringBuffer y(StringBuffer s) {
    return new StringBuffer(s.toString()).append("a");
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there any ordering issue associated with method x given that it mutates the input?
2. x could be considered as having a side effect, however, does this actually have any disadvantage over method y? Such as y being easier to parallelize?

Answer (score 2):

If you run `x` after `y` you get different output, although the invocation of `y` looks the same.

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
x(stringBuffer);
System.out.println(y(stringBuffer)); // gives aa

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
System.out.println(y(stringBuffer)); // gives a
x(stringBuffer);
```

In this small example the internal state of the instance in `stringBuffer` determines the output, and the details of when which method is invoked is important for that.

`x` has a side effect, as it changes the state of the `StringBuffer` instance. There may be several advantages and disadvantages to that, and discussing those is out of scope.

PS: In Java use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Isn't the same true where you have no mutation i.e.:

int addOne(x) {
 return x + 1;
}

Even here calling this method with a different value of x will yield different results, even though no mutation takes place?

Comment: No, it is not the same. You need to regard the case that the provided values are the same, so _not_ a different value of `x`. If those inputs are the same, the order does not matter, the function will always provide the same result.

Comment: So is the issue that the StringBuffer is a mutable object, meaning that even if the same value is passed (i.e. the ref) the underlying object could have a different value depending on the order in which its called? If this is the case, is this not a problem with all mutable objects - even if they are passed to a method like y which does not mutate it?

Comment: It is mutable and it is mutated, this is the issue. The method `y` is "pure" and is not part of the problem, it just shows the effects.

Comment: You describe `y` as pure yet if we create another method like `y` thus:

    StringBuffer z(StringBuffer s) {
        return new StringBuffer(s.toString()).append("b");
    }

...then running z after y will still give different results (than y after z) even though both are `pure`.

So it seems that making a function "pure" in this case does not necessarily prevent the ordering issue that would occur with the method `x`?